# How to find last processed time of dimension in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have a list of around 100+ dimensions. Is there any way to check the last processing time of each dimension using DMV's in SSAS?.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

mmm the only thing I see in the

SELECT CUBE_NAME, LAST_DATA_UPDATE FROM $System.MDSCHEMA_CUBES

that reports the last process date/time. In the cube name you can find dimension names, please check if it is what you want.

(use new MDX query)